# Opposite of array_intersect

Tags: php

I'm looking for the opposite of the function `array_intersect`, basically a function that returns the element that are **not** present in **each** of the provided arrays.

Example:

```
$a1 = array(1, 2, 3);
$a2 = array(2, 3, 4);
$result = array(1, 4);
```

I know how to do it programmatically (I just have two array so `array_merge(array_diff($a1, $a2), array_diff($a2, $a1))` would do the job), but I'd like to know whether there's a built-in function that I can't find.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what youre looking for? To me it sounds pretty similar to array intersect.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot a **not** in the question, so it made no sense. Now it should be clear.

Comment: @Entropy Now it makes sense as *A* ∩ *B* is obviously not equivalent to *A* \ *B* ∪ *B* \ *A*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't builtin for that

I believe a language will never provide such a builtin function

Comment: because a langauge provides builtin func for most common cases. This isn't a common case

Answer (score 5):

Since `array_diff($a, $b) !== array_diff($b, $a)`
the inverse of array_intersect is:

```
array_merge(array_diff($a,$b), array_diff($b,$a));
```

Here it is in a PHPUnit test format:

```
class ArrayInverseTest {
    function testInverseArrayIntersect() {
        $a = array(1, 2, 3);
        $b = array(2, 3, 4);

        $this->assertEquals(
            array_values(array(1, 4)),
            array_values(array_merge(array_diff($a, $b), array_diff($b, $a)))
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not built in. Note that you can improve your solution:

```
array_merge($a1, array_diff($a2, $a1));
```

Comment: @Entropy And how does `array_intersect` not provide this result?

Comment: @Entropy I don't understand what you need. Your explanation is very confusing. Please provide a sample input and output.

Comment: Forgive me. I forgot a “ **not** ” when I corrected the question. Now it should be more clear. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for array union? http://es.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php